# How to count numbers in text format in a google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, text, numbers

I am importing a excel data to google sheets. Upon importing the numbers in excel sheet changes its format to text.
now the functions like countif() and sumif() doesnt work when the numbers are in text format?
Please suggest any work around for this ?
Thanks in advance
Preeths

Answer (score 0):

Select all the cells which are numbers and change the format to numbers (Use the format menu to format as Number). Keep in mind the Spreadsheet settings and locale for the setting of decimal separator (comma or point).

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately this is not the option i am looking for. I need a option to count the numbers using some functions or a code .